# Odoo Calculate tax via api

Tags: python, odoo

How do I trigger calculation of tax in odoo via ERPPEEK. 
I want to trigger the tax calculation without me calculating the tax. Is there some possibility from erppeek

I manually create the invoice header and line, I get all the product and tax details, and then I want the trigger.

My code is as below.

```
import erppeek
from datetime import datetime,date
api = erppeek.Client('http://127.0.0.1:8080','bitnami_openerp','**@gmail.com','******')
api.common.version()


#now create an invoice for the user
#Prepare data
#Get Currency
m_currency = api.model('res.currency')
r_currency = m_currency.read(['name=INR'],['id','name'])

#Get Company
m_company = api.model('res.company')
r_company = m_company.read(['name=Your Company'],['id','name'])

#Get Journal
m_journal = api.model('account.journal')
r_journal = m_journal.read(['name=Sales Journal'],['id','name'])

#Get Account
m_account = api.model('account.account')
r_account = m_account.read(['name=Sundry Debtors'],['id','name'])

#Get Partner
m_partner = api.model('res.partner')
r_partner = m_partner.read(['email=jayanth.bagare@gmail.com'],['id','name'])


#Get Account
m_account = api.model('account.account')
r_account = m_account.read(['id=190'],['id','name'])

#Get Product
m_product = api.model('product.product')
r_product = m_product.read(['id=2'],['id','lst_price','name'])

#Get Tax
m_tax = api.model('account.tax')
r_tax = m_tax.read(['id=49'],['id'])

#Consolidate Invoice Header
data = {"partner_id":r_partner[0]["id"],
        "account_id":r_account[0]["id"],
        "journal_id":r_journal[0]["id"],
        "company_id":r_company[0]["id"],
        "currency_id":r_currency[0]["id"],
        "amount_untaxed":r_product[0]["lst_price"],
        "reference_type":"none",
        "amount_tax":"12.36",
        "type":"out_invoice",
        "date_invoice":date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        "amount_total":r_product[0]["lst_price"] + 12.36
         }

print data
#Create the invoice header
m_invoice = api.model('account.invoice')
invoice_id = m_invoice.create(data)

#Create Invoice Lines

#Consolidate Invoice Lines


product_id = r_product[0]["id"]
price_unit = r_product[0]["lst_price"]
quantity = "1"
ln_invoice_id = invoice_id.id
account_id = r_account[0]["id"]

print 'Tax is ',r_tax[0]["id"]

data_line = {"product_id":r_product[0]["id"],
             "price_unit":r_product[0]["lst_price"],
             "quantity":quantity,
             "invoice_id":invoice_id.id,
             "account_id":r_account[0]["id"],
             "company_id":r_company[0]["id"],
             "partner_id":r_partner[0]["id"],
             "uos_id":1,
             "name":r_product[0]["name"],
             "invoice_line_tax_id":[(6,0,[r_tax[0]["id"]])]
             }

m_invoice_line = api.model('account.invoice.line')
invoice_line_id = m_invoice_line.create(data_line)

print invoice_line_id.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see that you already linking the Tax with invoice lines so that should take care of it but if that doesn't work then you can trigger the method [**`button_reset_taxes`**](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/account_invoice.py#L637) of the model `account.invoice` this will take of the tax calculation on whole invoice.

Possible code:

```
m_invoice = api.model('account.invoice')
m_invoice.button_reset_taxes(invoice_id)
```

or something similar I could wrong with erppeek syntax. But bottom line is to call `button_reset_taxes` at end of creating invoice and invoice lines

Bests

Comment: For those who created the invoice programmatically: call it without parameters: `m_invoice.button_reset_taxes()`

Answer (score 0):

```
[....]
invoice = api.model('account.invoice').create(data)
[....]
invoice_line = api.model('account.invoice.line').create(data_line)
invoice.button_reset_taxes()
```

Comment: you should also explain your answer, code only answers are not that helpful for future readers with same problem